# Showing that the function $f(x) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{2}{3^j}x_j$ defined on the binary strings $x = (x_1,x_2,\dots)$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

I'm interested in knowing whether my reasoning for the smallest index $k$ (explained below) when showing that $f$ is continuous is correct.

I am working under the assumption that the topology of $\mathbb{R}$ is the standard one, i.e. open interval $(x - r, x + r)$ is an open neighborhood for a point $x \in \mathbb{R}$ etc. Let $X = \{0, 1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$, i.e. the set of all binary strings. I am given that the sets $U_j = \{x\in X\mid x_j = 0\}$ and $V_j = \{x \in X\mid x_j = 1\}$ form a prebasis for $X$. That is, the basis of $X$ is formed by sets in which we know finitely many values of the binary string elements.

Let $r > 0$ be arbitrary but fixed and $x \in X$. We are trying to show that there exists a neighborhood $S$ of $x$ in $X$ s.t. $f[S] \subset (f(x) - r, f(x) + r)$. My idea is to form the neighborhood $S$ s.t. $\forall y \in S: y_j = x_j, j = 1,\dots,k$ for some $k$ so that $|f(y) - f(x)| < r$. One can show that $\sum_{j=k}^\infty \frac{2}{3^j} < r \Longleftrightarrow \frac{3}{r} < 3^k$. Therefore, isn't the smallest such $k$ given by $k := \max\{0, 1 + \lceil\log_3(r/3)\rceil\}$?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on $x$ and $r$, this may not be the smallest $k$ that works for choosing $S$, and I think you want floor instead of ceiling if you care about that precision, but otherwise looks right.